# How to reload ngTable with successful Post

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I found similar posts on this topic but they include ngTable pagination. I have that feature disabled and I am unable to refresh the table after a successful Post. tableParams.reload is not doing anything. I also don't understand why the data is not updated on its on, isn't Angular supposed to update the view when the model changes?

```
// Table
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 100,          // count per page
    sorting: {
        foo: 'asc'     // initial sorting
    }
}, {
    counts: [], // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        $http.get('/api/apiMasterItem/')
           .success(function (data, status) {
               var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
               $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

           });
    }
});
$scope.editId = -1;

$scope.setEditId = function (pid) {
    $scope.editId = pid;
}
//Post MasterItem
$scope.addMasterItem = function () {
    var newMasterItem = $scope.newMasterItem
    MasterItemPost.post(newMasterItem)
        .success(function () {
            notification.success();
        }).error(function () {
            notification.error();
        })
    console.log(newMasterItem);
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
    $scope.newMasterItem.MLItemCode = '',
    $scope.newMasterItem.MLItemDescription = '',
    $scope.newMasterItem.MLItemUOM = '',
    $scope.newMasterItem.MLItemPrice = ''
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update `total` property as well,after recieving data,regardless of using pagination or not

#### controller

```
...
getData: function ($defer, params) {
        $http.get('/api/apiMasterItem/')
           .success(function (data, status) {
               var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
               // update table params
               params.total(data.length);
$defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));                    
           });
```

Comment: can u post more code,view of table code  and try to put reload inside sucsess of POST request

Comment: k, sorry for the delay. yes i will get that posted

Comment: moving the reload function inside the success of the Post worked! thanks